# batch export psd files to png

Tags: action, photoshop

I have thousands of psd files to save as png. The psd files are not different, except for a small text in the center of a image. Is there a way to automate the job?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes. Open your actions window. Create new action. Record yourself opening, saving the file as png and closing the file.

Then under File -> Automate -> Batch. Point it to your psd folder and select your action. It should run through the files saving them as pngs.

A quick google search may help if you're new to actions.

edited per author input :}

Comment: The action must be: open one file, save the file. If I don't open a file it saves thousands of copies of the same image. Thank you.

Comment: Whoops! it's been over a year since I've used it haha, sorry about that. Thought the batch function would auto-open the files.

Comment: In my experience, if you are using a new version of Photoshop and you use Export as PNG for the sake of quickness, you should override the save as process while running the action. That's why use Save As -> and choose PNG for file type while recording your actions.

Answer (score 7):

[XnView](http://www.xnview.com/en/) does the job pretty well. It can batch convert most files into most formats. It also has batch transformations and batch renaming among other things.

I use it regularly to convert PSDs to JPG/PNG/GIF.

Comment: This worked great for me since I only wanted to convert some files within a directory.  Photoshop had no easy way to only process *some* files.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. Photoshop is not very good at save as png while recording it as action.

Answer (score 2):

I  would use Irfanview 's powerful batch engine. Free and super-fast.

- Go to the Folder in Irfanview Thumnails
- Select all files
- Rightclick and "Start batch dialog with selected files"
- Select PNG as output format.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can make a Photoshop action to save the png and than run it via batch. This unfortunately gets tricky when you want to use this action option and specify the destination where the processed files are saved.

Enter Dr. (Russell) Brown’s Image Processor Pro, an extension for Photoshop that does exactly what most people need. It's dead simple and can even stack multiple processes and output formats/destinations to each file.

It's part of Dr. Brown’s Services
   - http://russellbrown.com/scripts.html