# Photoshop CS5 Batch Action Only Working For The First File

Tags: file, png, photoshop

I have a folder with a bunch of PSDs that I want to save as PNGs. I created an action to open a file, save it as a PNG, then close the file. Then when I go to File > Automate > Batch and run the action, it correctly saves the first image as a PNG, but then begins saving the rest of the files as copies of the PSD. Has anyone used an action to save a batch of PSDs to PNGs before?

I have checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001276/batch-export-psd-files-to-png) and [this one](https://www.quora.com/What-are-good-ways-to-batch-convert-PSD-to-JPG-or-PNG) as well as a few other of the top Google search results but I'm not finding an answer as to why it only correctly saves for the first file. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

**Start Action**

File Open → Save As png → Close File → Stop Recording Action

**Begin Batch**

Automate → Batch → Choose Source Folder & Destination Folder

Check Override Action "Open"

Check Override "Save As"

[image: Files]

[image: Actions]

[image: Batch]