# Batch Process PDFs to PNGs in Photoshop

Tags: pdf, automation, batch-processing, photoshop

I'm trying to batch process PDFs to PNGs in Photoshop. So far it only works if I have all the files already open. If I set it to open the files for me, it opens then, but does not run the Action steps. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Try with save as or shourt cut ctrl+shft+s to png. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here I show how to Batch PSD to PNG and it should work with PDF.

[Photoshop CS5 Batch Action Only Working For The First File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39397833/photoshop-cs5-batch-action-only-working-for-the-first-file/39403777#39403777)

Do you need to export each page in a PDF to a PNG? Does each PDF have a different amount of pages?